# Power on Arduino on tilt signal

Tags: arduino, switches

I need to turn an Arduino on when something triggers an independently powered tilt sensor; the Arduino needs then to stay awake and use an output pin to switch itself off. I couldn't find an example of what I need on the internet, and the only kind of circuit I came up with (but not tested) involves 2 relays, which doesn't sound good to me (although I'm not an expert).

Comment: Which accelerometer?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a tilt sensor (I'm editing the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self latching relay circuit, should work. Just one relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGnqUN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As long as the tilt switch is open, the circuit is off. Once the tilt switch closes, the PNP transistor is turned on through R1, which enables the relay to latch. The PNP transistor's base is connected to an arduino digital pin, which must be driven output low to turn the PNP off, breaking the power to the relay coil. The PNP needs to be sized to handle the coil current, and the relay must be able to carry the needed arduino current and coil current.

**The other option** is replacing (or paralleling) the arduino's 5v regulator with a better one, that has an enable pin, and using a circuit like this question asker has: [Protecting Microcontroller Input Pins from Soft Power Switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/65190/17178) They used a 74LVC1G80 Flip-Flop to toggle a 5v regulator with an Enable/Shutdown pin. Only a few tens of microamps used.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of powering the Arduino off, put the MCU into power-down and have the tilt sensor generate an interrupt to wake it up. See the "Power Management and Sleep Modes" section of the MCU datasheet to see what you can use and how as an interrupt during power-down. You'll want to use [`avr/sleep.h`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__sleep.html) and [`avr/interrupt.h`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) to handle them.

Alternately, prescale the system clock down during quiet times and prescale it back up when a signal is received. See the "System Clock and Clock Options" section of the datasheet and [`avr/power.h`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__power.html) for this.

In either case, shut off the subsystems you won't be using so that they don't draw power ("Power Management and Sleep Modes", [`avr/power.h`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__power.html)).

Comment: Is it possible to completely power off the Arduino and wake it up using a separate circuit?

Comment: @Daniele: Sure, but the added complexity and reduced flexibility may not be worth the few tens of microamps saved.

Comment: Fair enough. The thing is that I want to obtain at least a month of battery life for the circuit, so I was really trying to minimise every energy usage. Can you point me to circuit I can use to completely power off the Arduino waking it up when the tilt sensor moves?